# How to plot multiple data sets on Matplotlib Axes3D scatter without deleting previous data?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have a for loop which goes as the following:

```
for index, t in enumerate(Coords_at_different_energies):

    fig0 = pylab.figure(0)

    ax0 = Axes3D(fig0)

    arr_t = np.array(t)

    ax0.scatter(arr_t[:,0], arr_t[:,1], arr_t[:,2], color = colors[index])

pyplot.show()
```

where Coords_at_different_energies is a list of lists of coordinates and colors is a list of colors.

When I run it, only the last data set to be plotted seems to remain i.e. I think the loop overwrites previous data sets with each iteration. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `figure` creates a new figure, erasing whatever was already there.  Likewise, using `Axes3D(fig0)` creates a new axes, erasing the old.  Move the figure and axes creation outside of your loop and do only the actual plotting inside the loop.